# How to stop Asterisk from repeating "SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized" messages

Tags: asterisk

I am writing a small Node module to make a simple SIP call through Asterisk. I am not using any of the JS libraries for reasons not relevant to this question. When I send the INVITE message, as expected, it returns with a "SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized" message and a nonce to be used to build a hash to be sent in the response. All that is fine. My problem is that this 401 message keeps repeating/retransmitting. How do I stop this so I get only one SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized message and not multiple ones? Why does it keep repeating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

1. The authentication (challenge/response) is wrong.
2. Signaling (SIP) is one way due to routing/nat/firewall problems.

I'd recommend to find out which one is the case and then investigate further.

Comment: It was the first one... I mean there was a problem in the response, not with the hash calculation but elsewhere in the syntax.  Corrected and works now.

Comment: Can you take a look at this issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998787/asterisk-digest-authentication-for-sip-invite-gives-user-mismatch-error).  Somewhere I am not constructing my SIP messages properly. Can you please take a quick look. I have desperately tried everything to no avail.